# Django - check if user is authenticated for every url

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

On my html, I can check if the user is logged in by using the following syntax:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div id="display_something">...</div>
{% else %}
  <p>Please Log in</p>
{% endif %}
```

But what should I do if I want to check if the user is authenticated for every html file I am rendering? Do I have to copy and paste that `{% if ... %}` block for every single html file? What is the Django's way of handling this issue? What's the good practice?

Comment: Check out this link, it may be helpful for what you're trying to do: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your `base.html`, add your check

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% block page %}
  {% endblock %}
{% else %}
  <p>Please Log in</p>
{% endif %}
```

then with all your other pages, add `{% extends 'base.html' %}` at the top. You will need to give it a relative link to `base.html`. 
Then the rest of your code on that page needs to sit between tags like below.

```
{% block page %}
<!-- all your html code here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Notice that after `block`, you need to have the same name. for this example, it is `page` but you can pick your own variable name.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't handle the authentication logic in the template (for the entire site), instead you can use the [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) on your views.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```