# Django Show Code in Template if Logged In

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Laravel Blade template, I can do this to show code only if a user is logged in:

```
@auth
<div>Show code only if logged in.</div>
@endauth
```

Does Django have a template tag or something similar that does the equivalent? E.g.:

```
{% auth %}
<div>Show code only if logged in.</div>
{% endauth %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since I found more of what I was looking. In Django, they're called "decorators," e.g., @login_required.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Added: 11/02/2021.

Answer (score 2):

In Django templates you should check for `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304745/django-check-if-user-is-authenticated-for-every-url) for more.